# logging from python multiprocessing, one logfile per thread, log-messages from imported module(s)

Tags: python-2.7, logging, python-multiprocessing

I have a python script which initiates multiple instances of a class foo and then executes the method 'run' of the class using multiprocessing.pool.map like this:

```
import multiprocessing.dummy as mp
import foo_class

def run_instance(instance):
    return instance.run()

for arguments in list_of_arguments:
    instances.append(foo_class.Foo(arguments))

mp.pool.map(run_instance, instances)
```

which works very well. The thing giving me trouble is that in the constructor of the class a logger and filehandler is initiated, and i want to have a separate logfile for each instance of the class:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
        self.logfile = logging.FileHandler(name + '.log')
```

(i omitted the formatter and log-level, since it's not part of this question.) The problem now is, that with the way described above, I get one logfile per instance, but the log-messages from all the instances go in every logfile.
If I name the logger, like this:

```
self.logger = getLogger(name + '_logger')
```

then the log-messages will be assigned to the files correctly, but all log-messages from imported modules, in which I initialized module loggers like this:

```
module_logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

will no longer be displayed in the logfiles, since the module logger does not recognize the differently named loggers in the class instances as parent loggers (which works perfectly with the above approach).

Is there any way to obtain per-instance logfiles with log-messages from imported modules also being written to these files?

Answer (score 1):

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
```

This doesn't work, because, as [the documentation states](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html#logging.getLogger), calling `getLogger` without an argument will just return the root logger (which is always the same).

If you want the class instances' loggers to be child of others, you need to make it so explicitly. So, if your module logger is named `X`, you do

`self.logger = getLogger(X + "." + name + '_logger')`

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply!

actually, what I want is that the module_logger be the child to the class logger, which won't work if I give names to the class loggers explicitly, since I then would need to pass the name of the class instance logger to the imported module.

Comment: @Steffen I don't think it makes much sense to have a module logger be a child of a logger in a class instance - maybe you're misunderstanding how modules work? A module exists independently of any such instance, and of any `import` statements. If you `import` a module in multiple places, you get a reference to the same object